# Simple play/pause toggle for a volume slider done with input?

Tags: javascript, jquery, audio, input

Can't seem to figure out how to make this play/pause properly. I've got the volume control working perfectly, but as soon as I add the new script and take it off autoplay, it doesn't work. All I am trying to create is a simple play/pause button, or even just an enable/disable audio button (I know that those are different). What's the best way to go about this?

HTML:

```
<audio id="song" src="assets/audio/supermariotheme.mp3">
</audio>
<button onClick="play()">play</button>
<input type="range" id="volume" min="0" max="1" step="0.1" value="1" />
```

JS:

```
$('#volume').on('change', function() {
    $('#song').prop("volume", this.value);
});

function play() {
    var audio = document.getElementById('song');
    if (audio.paused) {
        audio.play();
    }else{
        audio.currentTime = 0
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is working: http://jsfiddle.net/Sqx48/

```
function play() {
    var audio = document.getElementById('song');
    if (audio.paused) {
        audio.play();
    } else {
        audio.pause();
    }
}
```

Or

```
function play() {
    var audio = document.getElementById('song');
    audio[audio.paused ? 'play' : 'pause']();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd avoid using `onClick="play()"` property. Use jquery instead:

```
$("button").click(function(){
    var audio = $("#song")[0];
    if (audio.paused) {
        audio.play();
    }else{
        audio.currentTime = 0
    }
});
```